VLOOKUP Not looking (dependent on two cells in one sheet plus another in a different sheet)
We have this data set

The "SOW" column is a drop down
We also have the lookups in a different sheet

We want to be able to type a name in column A (that is already in Lookups), and then select a SOW type (cheese, bread, carrots etc.) and have the rate (the dollar amount in the lookups) pop up. Our vlookup isn't working, and we aren't sure why.
=VLOOKUP(A2,Lookups!A:N,MATCH(Data!E1,Lookups!C:I,0),FALSE)

Please note it's matching the name, not ID or other stuff. I can't seem to attach the excel sheet :(
Tried vlookup different one, we want to avoid getpivotdata because there's going to be a ton of entries under a bunch of different names

You could try using the following formula:


=XLOOKUP(A2,Lookups!A:A,FILTER(Lookups!C:N,Data!E2&" 24"=Lookups!$C$1:$N$1))


And here is the quick fix to your existing formula:
=VLOOKUP(A2,Lookups!A:N,MATCH(Data!E2&" 24",Lookups!$1:$1,0),FALSE)


Or You can use wildcard operator *
=VLOOKUP(A2,Lookups!A:N,MATCH(E2&"*",Lookups!$A$1:$N$1,0),0)


Since OP says its not working as per their comments below for them here is another screenshot to validate the formula is working:



Thank you! So it worked for the first cell (the wildcard operator), but upon formula dragdown (and also tried copy), it started pulling down the A column vaue (the name) @mayukh-bhattacharya

It still works on my end. Not sure where it is not working for you , as a reference you can see Kelly's output

@racheljessica yes i just want to know how it is not working, can you explain further. saying not working doesn't helps us to know where it is failing to deliver.

Hi - I pulled the formula onto our spreadsheet with actual data, it's basically only working on the first cell. Once we drag it down, it shows the value of the name - in this case, cell D, would show "Kelly Kapoor" not rate

Please upload a screenshot to show how it is not working. Because whatever you have posted based on that the same is working on my end

Hi - we managed to get it working with your wildcard formula - all good! Thank you!!
